# Check empty result with mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Firstly, sorry for the title but I really don't know how to say that.
I have 3 tables for storing sections, pages and reads.

The tables are...

**sections**

```
idsection
sectiontitle
```

**pages**

```
idpage
pagetitle
idsection
```

**reads**

```
idread
idpage
time
```

I have a simple query to list the `sections` like -

```
SELECT * FROM sections WHERE 1;
```

But I need to show if the `section` has been totally `read`, which means *all* `pages` with the same `idsection` have been `read`. The only ways I can imagine are complex queries and that it will be simpler to use a php `for` script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try on below:

```
select * from section s where idsection not in (select page.idsection from 
page where 
page.idsection=s.idsection and idpage not in (select idpage from read));
```

I use not in because u need to check all pages instead of 1 of the page.
So we should get the page that are not in read (unread) and put not in there.

If u have 1 section that have 5 pages and all is read, it will give you empty result on subquery making ur main query selecting the session.

If u have 1 section that have 10 pages that only 9 pages is read, it will give u pages no 10 in subquery and make your section in main query empty (not in).

Comment: I choose your answer because it's the mostly understandable for me. Thanks

Comment: well the main thing is, does the query above helping and works?

Comment: It seems to work, but it also seems simplier in my case to use php for the job because my tables are not as simple as that and the query is too big.

Answer (score 0):

This Should work, but it is using group by, so You have to add each item You want to select from sections table in group by as well.

```
  SELECT        dbo.sections.idsection, dbo.sections.sectiontitle, CASE WHEN SUM(dbo.[read].idread) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS AllRead
    FROM            dbo.page INNER JOIN
                             dbo.sections ON dbo.page.idsection = dbo.sections.idsection LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             dbo.[read] ON dbo.page.idpage = dbo.[read].idpage
    GROUP BY dbo.sections.idsection, dbo.sections.sectiontitle
```